# How on Angular 2 "this" keyword from subscribe refers to the class?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

i have a subscription for observable, so when it finish i need it to call a function from this class, the problem is the "this" keyword refers to the subscription and not to the class scope. 
code:

```
export class GoogleMapComponent{

Position:object;

constructor(public MapFunctionsProvider: MapFunctionsProvider) { 

  let posObservable = this.MapFunctionsProvider.getPosition();

      posObservable.subscribe(data =>{
          this.Position = data;
          this.createMap();// this keyword refers to the subscription
      }); 

      function createMap(){
        console.log('run')

    }
}
```

**How can i call createMap() without declare new variable of "this" keyword?**

Comment: No. `this` refers to the GoogleMapComponent object. But GoogleMapComponent doesn't have any method named createMap(). createMap() is a function defined inside the constructor. Everything would be clearer if you properly indented your code. If you want to leave the createMap() definition as is, then use `createMap()` instead of `this.createMap()`.

Answer (score 2):

implement the function outside of the constructor.because `this` refers to the `GoogleMapComponent` class

```
export class GoogleMapComponent {

    Position: object;

    constructor(public MapFunctionsProvider: MapFunctionsProvider) {

        let posObservable = this.MapFunctionsProvider.getPosition();

        posObservable.subscribe(data => {
            this.Position = data;
            this.createMap(); // this keyword refers to the subscription
        });


    }

    createMap(): any {
        console.log('run')

    }
}
```

Comment: or do not use `this`

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with Angular and is a ES6 new feature.

When ever you're using arrow functions `()=>()`, `this.` will always refer to the class instance and doesn't matter how nested you go.

You can still use `function(){}` if you don't want this behaviour.